# opencart site becomes extremely slow after migrating to new server

Tags: php, windows, iis, opencart, opencart2.x

Problem: site becomes extremely slow after migrating to a new (better) server, and it **seems to be related to php image rendering**?

Site setup: Opencart 2.0.3.1, ~100 products, ~10 categories. Uses customized theme and VQMod. Site is hosted with IIS (PHP 5.6, IIS PHP Manager) on Windows Server 2012 R2 (both old and new). MySQL DB that supports opencart is running on the same machine.

Old machine: Pentium G2020T (2-core 2-thread, 2.5GHz) with 10G DDR3 running Windows server 2012 R2. (There is an on board NVidia GT520 card, if that matters)

New Machine: Xeon-D 1540 (8-core 16-thread, 2.0-2.6GHz) with 32G DDR4 running Windows Server 2012 R2 (Aspeed AST2400 onboard video card, if that matters)

**Symptoms:**
On the old setup, site loads immediately without any sort of delay, and it is very responsive when navigating through different products. On the new setup, however, it takes about 15-20 seconds just to load the home page, same applies to each individual product.

**More details:**
The 2 servers have identical software setup. The way I migrated the site is by copying over the entire opencart directory over, plus doing the MySQL dump for site data. I cleaned up the cache directories (system/cache, vqmod/cache, etc) after the migration. What I noticed was that it seems like this is somehow related to php rendering images - any page with images loads very slow (on the new machine only). During the load, the "php-cgi" process took about 80% CPU time of a single core on the new host (and persisted for about 20 seconds). It seems php-gd2.dll is eating all that CPU cycles.

**What I suspect:**
I have tried to install a fresh copy of opencart from the Microsoft Web Platform installer and the site was pretty responsive. So I think it rules out any hardware related issues. Here is my list of suspects & questions:

- Am I missing anything in the migration process?
- Does PHP use any graphics hardware to render images on Windows? I have a hard time believing that having an integrated video card was the reason for fast rendering on the old machine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it possible the old machine had a means of caching the altered images to a folder or temp storage to which the new machine is preventing access?  I am not familiar with opencart, but most thumbnail and image resizing that I've encountered server-side caches the results somehow.

Comment: Just a tip: try setting up a centos/ubuntu server at digitalocean and do the same install. I have a hard time understanding why you need a dedicated for a site this small (?)

Check if the site works there with for example sentora/ cwp (Centos web panel or something)

Comment: It is indeed the caching issue - it looks like during the migration process I failed to clean up the image caching and php somehow could not create new cache thumbnails but was trying to do the resizing every time the specific page was requested.

Comment: It was an incomplete site and thus very small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue - the image cache was not cleaned up during the migration. This caused the engine to try creating the image thumbnails every time the page is requested. After cleaning up the cache the issue was resolved.

Two things remain strange to me:

1. After a failed caching attempt, why doesn't php-gd2 clean up the cached files and recreate new ones?
2. The php-gd2 library seems to be very inefficient processing jpeg images - I am still having a hard time understanding the fact that it took a Broadwell 8-core machine 20 seconds to process ~10 pictures (each of them is about 4M in size). Is there any alternative to php-gd2 for image processing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have 50 reputation to comment on sqexpress's answer but experienced a similar issue with OpenCart 2.0.3.1 under IIS8 on Windows Server 2012 R2 with PHP 5.4.45 and 7.0.7.

Changing line #13 on /catalog/model/tool/image.php from

```
if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image) || (filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image) > filectime(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image))) {
```

to

```
if (!is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image) || (filemtime(DIR_IMAGE . $old_image) > filemtime(DIR_IMAGE . $new_image))) {
```

resolves the issue of cache files being re-created on every page load when the original was a file introduced by migrating to a new server.

OpenCart originally used filemtime back in version 1.5.6.4.  Unsure when or why it changed to filectime.

Comment: You just saved my life 5 years later